# Why does my Robocopy always copy one file but not the other?

Tags: backup, batch-file, robocopy, windows-backup

Trying to learn Robocopy for a basic backup plan, and I tried this in a bat file:

```
@echo off
echo "Hello World!"
robocopy C:\Testfolder Z:\Testfolder
pause
```

where Z: is a network drive (a usb external drive connected to the router's usb port)

There are only two files in C:\Testfolder - 02.jpg and 02-03.jpg.

The first time I ran this, it created Testfolder on Z: and copied both images over.

Curious what would happen, I ran it again - this time, the on-screen messages say it copied 02.jpg, but skipped 02-03.jpg.  Same thing with re-running it again.

Why would this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, robocopy only copies files that it thinks have changed since the last time you ran it. You can confirm this by seeing the status at the end of the copy. It should say Files Skipped is 1. You might need to include the `/v` option to get better details.

Because you are copying to a network based drive connected to your router there is a good chance that there is a file time bug and it is causing robocopy to see a different date and time on one of the destination files. File attribute issues are common with Linux based samba shares such as what is most likely used by your router. This would explain why it keeps re-copying one file if it hasn’t changed. You might try the `/timfix` parameter to see if it will correct the time on the files and will stop re-copying unchanged files.

If you want robocopy to copy files that are the same and unchanged, add the `/is` option.

More info here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Comment: Bang on.  With /timfix I got the same result.  But then your post reminded me I had read something about this elsewhere and went back to find it.  /FFT fixed it.  Now it skips both files, as desired.  Thanks.